# Increase certain elements by 1 in a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I want to increase certain elements in `I1` by `1` according to locations specified by `T`. I present the current and expected outputs.

```
I1= [17, 19, 30, 31, 34, 46]

T=[1, 5]

New=[i+1 for i in I1 if i in T]
print(New)
```

The current output is

```
[]
```

The expected output is

```
I1= [17, 20, 30, 31, 34, 47]
```

Comment: `for i in T: I1[i] += 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sort of thing is much easier in numpy:

```
I1 = np.array(I1)
I1[T] += 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate) and `if/else` in [`list_comprehension`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0202/).

```
# We can save a set of T if we have repeated items in 'T' and if 'I1' is a large array
set_T = set(T)

New = [item+1 if idx in set_T else item for idx, item in enumerate(I1)]
print(New)
```

Output:`[17, 20, 30, 31, 34, 47]`